# What Character Encoding Is This?

Tags: character-encoding

I need to clean up some file containing French text. Problem is that the files erroneously contain multiple encodings within the same file.

I think some sections are ISO8859-1 (Latin 1) but other parts have text encoded in single byte characters that look like 'extended' ASCII. In other words, it is UTF-7 encoding plus the following:

- 0x82 for é (e acute)
- 0x8a for è (e grave)
- 0x88 for ê (e circumflex)
- 0x85 for à (a grave)
- 0x87 for ç (c cedilla)

What encoding is this?

Comment: did you look on Windows-1252 encoding too?

Comment: (I removed the utf-7 tag; UTF-7 is something completely different and not another name for ASCII.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the original IBM PC encoding, [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: Yep. Don't see it much these days!

Answer (score 0):

This website [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c7/index.htm) shows a link with 0x87 for cedilla.  I haven't look much further than this, but I bet the rest of your information could be found here as well.

Comment: That's capital-C-cedilla, and only mentions 0x87 as the second byte of a UTF-8 sequence by coincidence.